# Conjectured upper bound $\frac{\Gamma(x+n)}{\Gamma(x)}$ and limit at infinity

Tags: inequality, examples-counterexamples, exponentiation, gamma-function, conjectures

> > Let $x\geq 1$ a real number and $n\geq 3$ a natural number then we have :
> >     $$\frac{\Gamma(x+n)}{\Gamma(x)}\leq \Bigg(\frac{nx+\Big(\frac{n(n-1)}{2}\Big)}{\frac{n}{2}}-\Bigg(x^x(x+1)^{x+1}(x+2)^{x+2}\cdots(x+n-1)^{x+n-1}\Bigg)^{\frac{1}{nx+\Big(\frac{n(n-1)}{2}\Big)}}\Bigg)^{n}$$

It's a conjecture but first for me :$\frac{\Gamma(x+n)}{\Gamma(x)}=x(x+1)\cdots(x+n-1)$.So if there are problems of notations feel free to correct me . I have tested for $n\leq 25$. If it's true I find this inequality beautiful . I conjecture also that the difference tends to $0$ when $x$ tends to infinity . I have tried Gautschi's inequality and more without success  .

If you have an idea to solve it...

Any helps is greatly appreciated .

Thanks in advance for all your contributions .

Comment: Watson's lemma, applied to a beta integral, gives $\Gamma(x+s)/\Gamma(x)\sim x^s$, with higher asymptotic terms also available. Would this be suitable for you, or do you want a more combinatorial/algebraic argument?

Comment: @paulgarrett I accept the truth but it would be amazing (for me) to see a combinatorial/algebraic proof !

Comment: @RiverLi Have you an idea to solve this monster ?If you solve the case $n=3$ I will give you the bounty .Thanks my dear.

Comment: It would really help us to see HOW you got the result

Comment: Very intereting problem, for sure. Could you clarify how you did obtain this inequality ? This could help us. Cheers and thanks for giving the link to your question.  :)